# Writing a select query using 2 tables and 2 conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Im having trouble writing the logic to see if an id from one table appears 12 or more times in another table.

The question is asking:
"There are some academics that have written more than 12 papers and there are some
academics are interested in fields that have the word “database” in the title. List the
academic number of each academic that meet either or both of these conditions."

this is what iv written so far

```sql
SELECT acnum 
FROM academic 
WHERE acnum IN (
SELECT panum 
FROM paper 
WHERE title LIKE '%database%');
```

Also some information about the database relation/tables.

scheme of the tables possible needed:

```
AUTHOR( panum*, acnum* )
PAPER( panum , title)
```

Sample Data:

```
PAPER values(100, 'Intro to programming');
PAPER values(101, 'Intro to database systems');
PAPER values(102, 'Intro to database management');
PAPER values(103, 'Intro to computing');
PAPER values(104, 'Intro to database analysis');

AUTHOR values (101, 25);
AUTHOR values (102, 25);
AUTHOR values (103, 25);
AUTHOR values (104, 25);
AUTHOR values (105, 25);
AUTHOR values (106, 25);
AUTHOR values (107, 25);
... up until 12 that all have same acnum (25).
```

Comment: Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: There is no relationship between academic and paper so you need to use the joining/link/xref table author to get from academic to paper, and since you are only getting acnum from academic you can probably drop this table entirely from the query,

Comment: oh okay so i can just use the table "Author' and "paper" tables to get the result? also my main question is how to write the logic to find if a acnum has 12 more panum attached to it, so how could i check to see if the Author table has repeated the same acnum 12 or more times but with a different panum for every one of them in the table? (i think that will give me the answer im looking for)

Comment: @HuseyinYesiler please read the link shared in the first comment; pics dont help (especially ER diagrams), instead please provide some relevant sample data so that question can make some sense, and answerable.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya is this what you mean? not sure if i understood the article properly

Comment: Your tables don't have any information on interests or the other information needed to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join 5 tables and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select ac.acnum 
from academic ac
left join author a on a.acnum = ac.acnum
left join paper p on p.panum = a.panum and p.title like '%database%'
left join interest i on i.acnum = ac.acnum
left join field f on f.fieldnum = i.fieldnum and f.title like '%database%'
group by ac.acnum
having 
  count(distinct p.panum) > 12
  or
  sum(f.title is not null) > 0
```

If the 1st condition is not about the academics that have written at least 12 papers about `'database'` but **any** paper, then remove the condition:

```
and p.title like '%database%'
```